# Convert a JSON string to a JSONObject in java pojo using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have my class (assume getters/setters defined) :

```
public class Keyword
    {
        private String keyword;
        private JSONObject keywordData;
    }
}
```

And my JSON looks like this :

```
{
    "keyword": "help",
    "keywordData": {
        "line1": "This is line1",
        "line2": "this is line 2"
    }
}
```

I am able to get the "help" word in my java class, but not keywordData.

**I want to save the data inside keywordData as JSON itself.** (The number of lines will increase, thats why I want to store it as JSON itself. Also, I don't want to use a list for line1, line2.. and son on)

Does anyone know what's wring with my POJO class?

Comment: If you're using GSON, try with `JsonObject` instead. It works for me.

Comment: I am using org.json.JSONObject, tried using JsonObject also, didn't work :(

Comment: For which reason? Can't you use `com.google.gson.JsonObject` ? It definitely works for me.

Comment: I tried using com.google.gson.JsonObject but its still not working

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/1a3423abe0e4d9a80748 and tell me if it works or not

Comment: @AlexisC. I tried ur code, its not working for me, my gson lib version is 2.2.2

Comment: I'm using version 2.3.1. If you can update the lib; update it.